# Has Tensorflow training output style changed?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have been working on my deep learning model for a while. Today, when I started the model training, I noticed only a fraction of my dataset is being trained and the size of data used in each epoch changes with the batch size.

```
print(mixture_train_shaped.shape)
print(clear_train_shaped.shape)
model.fit(mixture_train_shaped, clear_train_shaped,
         validation_split=0.2,
         epochs=40,
         batch_size=32, 
         shuffle=True,
         verbose=1
        )
```

When I run this code, this is what I see.

```
(51226, 129, 8, 4)
(51226, 129, 1, 1)
Epoch 1/40
1281/1281 [===========]
Epoch 2/40
1281/1281 [===========]
```

In my previous training outputs, the model would use the entire set in one epoch. On the above example though, the training set has 40,980 sample and each epoch trains only 40,980/32=1281. In a way, every epoch trains a single batch.

```
Train on 47 samples, validate on 6 samples
Epoch 1/5000
47/47 [==========]
```

I haven't changed the code. Is every epoch still using the entire training set or has it changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the previous versions of Colab, the training set size was shown. With this update, the batch numbers are shown in the progress bar but no change in how many items have been trained for the model.